# ng-repeat does not seem to rebind ng-click on a re-rendering

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat assigned to a row in a table as shown below.  When the user selects a down arrow in the row, the method moveDown gets executed, which reorders the list (see code).

When I look at the DOM, everything looks right - The rows are reordered, and the ng-click sees the newly assigned seqNbr.

Better explanation:

Initially first row shows data-ng-click='moveDown(0);' second data-ng-click='moveDown(1);'

After selecting the first one, the first and second row trade places.  The seqNbr are swapped in the objects and list is reordered, then the ng-repeate is reexecuted.

Now the DOM shows that the NEW first row has:  data-ng-click='moveDown(0);' and the old first row, now the second row, has data-ng-click='moveDown(1);'

However if I select the new first row, what gets executed is moveDown(1) (the old method associated with that row).  Its as if the DOM is updated, but not the method binding.

HTML:

```
    <tr class='evidencerow' data-ng-repeat="e in data.evidence">
        <td><div class='assertion webdiv' style='height:4em;'
                 data-ng-dblclick='openReference(e);'>
                <span data-ng-bind-html-unsafe='e.assertion'></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='img/UpArrow16x16.png' data-ng-hide='$first'
                         data-ng-click='moveUp({{e.seqNbr}});' style='width:32px;'>
            <img src='img/DownArrow16x16.png' data-ng-hide='$last'
                         data-ng-click='moveDown({{e.seqNbr}});' style='width:32px;'>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

controller code:

```
$scope.moveUp = function(seq) {
    var recs = $scope.data.evidence.slice(0);
    recs[seq].seqNbr = seq - 1;
    if (_ev.notEmpty(recs[seq - 1])) {
        var s2 = seq - 1;
        recs[s2].seqNbr = seq;
    }
    recs.sort(_ev.compareSeqNbr);
    $scope.data.evidence = recs;
};

$scope.moveDown = function(seq) {
    var recs = $scope.data.evidence.slice(0);
    recs[seq].seqNbr = seq + 1;
    if (_ev.notEmpty(recs[seq + 1])) {
        var s2 = seq +1;
        recs[s2].seqNbr = seq;
    }
    recs.sort(_ev.compareSeqNbr);
    $scope.data.evidence = recs;
};
```

This behavior doesn't seem right to me.  The result is instead of the rows moving up and down, they toggle back and forth.

Comment: It's a bit hard to track, any chance of creating a fiddle we can look at?

Comment: janderson did a great one.  I need to get into the habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX5LE/243/).  I think it does what you're looking for.

I modified your `moveUp()` and `moveDown()` functions a bit and they now take the full "evidence" object rather than just a number.

```
$scope.moveUp = function(e) {
    var idx = $scope.data.evidence.indexOf(e);
    var removed = $scope.data.evidence.splice(idx, 1);
        $scope.data.evidence.splice(idx - 1, 0, removed[0]);
};

$scope.moveDown = function(e) {
    var idx = $scope.data.evidence.indexOf(e);
    var removed = $scope.data.evidence.splice(idx, 1);
        $scope.data.evidence.splice(idx + 1, 0, removed[0]);
};
```

Comment: Very clean solution - I like.  I am wondering what was broken about mine though...